# Missing parameters - unable to load CSV from s3 to neptune

Tags: amazon-neptune

I'm trying to load files from s3 to Neptune using the `curl` command from the Neptune documentation:

```
curl -X POST \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    https://your-neptune-endpoint:port/loader -d '
    {
      "source" : "s3://bucket-name/object-key-name",
      "format" : "format",
      "iamRoleArn" : "arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/role-name",
      "region" : "region",
      "failOnError" : "FALSE",
      "parallelism" : "MEDIUM",
      "updateSingleCardinalityProperties" : "FALSE",
      "queueRequest" : "FALSE"
    }'
```

I entered all the parameters requested and receiving the following error: `missing required parameters`
[image: missing required parameters]

I tried to load the CSV from s3 to Neptune; I expected to receive a message with the load id but I got an error instead.

tried to change the source like the commet suggested and still the same error:
[image]

Comment: Can you please show the actual curl command and parameters used (no need to show the actual ARN and cluster name)? Please also add the full error message.

Comment: I just noticed the image of the error message, those fields need to be filled in, for example region might be "us-east-1"

Comment: @KelvinLawrence Ive added those parameters but for some reason it doesnt recognize them this is how i entered it  {'source':'https://s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/365**/graph_***/athletes.csv','format':'csv','iamRoleArn':'arn:aws:iam::5*****','region':'us-east-1', 'failOnError':'FALSE' ,'parallelism':'MEDIUM' ,'updateSingleCardinalityProperties':'FALSE','queueRequest':'FALSE'}

Comment: The source parameter needs to be the `s3://` URL.  So if your bucket name is `365**`, then it would be something like `s3://365**/graph_***/athletes.csv`.

Comment: @TaylorRiggan tried it your way and its still the same issue

Comment: How are you submitting this curl command, it kind of feels like something about the way curl is being issued is causing the issue? Curl and various command shells can be a bit finicky. I took your command and was able to get it to work using a test cluster. Please see the answer for the formatted command.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to take your command (substituting my server and credentials) and it worked fine. This is the command I used:

```bash
curl -X POST \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    https://my-cluster.cluster-aaaabbbbcccc.us-east-1.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182/loader -d '
    {
      "source" : "s3://bucket/prefix/myfile.csv",
      "format" : "csv",
      "iamRoleArn" : "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:role/NeptuneLoadFromS3",
      "region" : "us-east-1",
      "failOnError" : "FALSE",
      "parallelism" : "MEDIUM",
      "updateSingleCardinalityProperties" : "FALSE",
      "queueRequest" : "FALSE"
    }'
```